# Как обновлять строку в таблице Mysql пользователя по его id

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста. Код PHP я нашел на просторах интернета и он служил мне для записи новой строки в БД . И вот у меня загвоздка как преобразовать данный код в то чтобы он не создавал новую строку а редактировал существующую строку пользователя. Разумеется каждому пользователю присваивается совой id.

Я использую вот такой вот код значения clicks поступает после отправки формы с сайта.

```
<form method="POST">
   <input id="clickscountmysql" name="clicks" type="hidden">

   <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['clicks'])) {
    
    $clicks = $_POST['clicks'];
        
    $db_table = "cl_users";
        
        try {
            $db_adm = new PDO("mysql:host=$sql_db_host;dbname=$sql_db_name", $sql_db_user, $sql_db_pass);
            $db_adm->exec("set names utf8");

            $data = array( 
                'clicks' => $clicks,); 

            $query = $db_adm->prepare("INSERT INTO $db_table (clicks) values (:clicks)");
            $query->execute($data);
            $result = true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Ошибка!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        }
        
        if ($result) {
            echo '<script>console.log("Успешно PHP")</script>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: чтобы редактировать надо писать UPDATE  либо использовать INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: А ещё - необходимо наличие в структуре таблицы уникального индекса, который обнаружит, что запись с указанными характеристиками ужесуществует.

Comment: Если можно пожалуйста точнее с примером кода, я новичок в php для меня он пока дается сложновато.